# jQuery UI - Select a class from the range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a jQuery UI [range slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range), which I'm trying to get the value of the "left" attribute of the minimum and maximum handler.

To do so, I have this javascript code used with the #price_range, in this case, everything works fine.

```
function GetLeftValue(){
   var element = document.getElementById('price_range'),
   left = element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
   windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
   var num = (Number(((left / windowWidth) * 100).toFixed(1))+ "%");
   alert(num);
}
```

But when I'm trying to use it with the two handlers who have the following classes :

```
.ui-slider-handle .ui-corner-all .ui-state-default
```

I can't reach them using my js function with "getElementsByClassName()" of course :

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('class')
```

I tried every single one of the previous classes.

I also tried jQuery, related to my function, which i'm not really sure if it's a valid way to select elements :

```
var element = document.$('#slider-range > span:nth-child(2)') /*minimum handler*/
```

Finally, I thought that somehow, the element should be an id, so it can work properly, which I tried to add an Id to the previous classes:

```
$('.class').attr("id","myId");
```

Which is still failing to do what am I expecting.

Can anyone help me clear things up on this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
let minvalue = $(".ui-slider-handle:eq(0)").css("left");  
let maxvalue = $(".ui-slider-handle:eq(1)").css("left");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sguk2a39/

EDIT: had some typos.

Comment: Yes, seems like it's doing its job, i just need to convert the output into percentage which i'm working with in my function, but i still don't understund why my selector are not working !